# Unable to find image 'sensor1container:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sensor1container, repository does

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I'm a beginner in docker and I'm trying to create a container. I created the container and then I exited. I'm trying to reenter in the container but it gives me the following error: Unable to find image 'sensor1container:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sensor1container, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

I tried to create a new container with the same name of the first one and it gives me the following error: The container name "/Sensor1Container" is already in use by container "a2d05fd0c3536f5a76a83db2e3947cc48a15d2768fd3bcbe409802fa7c40ed14". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.

I don't see my container listed and I can't create a new one with that name.

How can I create a container that will remain there after I exit the page and how can I execute an application there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `docker ps` to show the running containers (there should be one that matches the hash ID printed in the error you mentioned).

To enter a BASH shell for that container, you can use the following:

```
docker exec -it a2d05fd0c3536f5a76a83db2e3947cc48a15d2768fd3bcbe409802fa7c40ed14 bash
```

This container must be stopped or renamed before you can make a new container:

Stop with docker container kill:

```
#replace container_id with a2d05fd0c3536f5a76a83db2e3947cc48a15d2768fd3bcbe409802fa7c40ed14 in this example
docker container kill container_id
```

Renaming:

```
docker container rename CONTAINER NEW_NAME
```

You can run a container with the `--rm` argument to make it stop after it completes its given task:

```
docker run --rm -it container:tag
```

If you want the container to persist in the background while it runs its given task, use `--detach` :

```
docker run --detach container:tag
```

See the docs for more information on these arguments: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/